# Custom filters to get product magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to filter with multiple category and custom attribute but the code its not working please let me know whats wrong with my code

```
$type1=array();
foreach($_REQUEST['type'] as $tyof)
{
$implodetype=$tyof.',';
$type1[]=$implodetype;
}
foreach($type1 as $categoryid){
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryid);
// get product collection, filter it by category, 
// add the color attribute to select to be able to filter using it later
$obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addCategoryFilter($category)
->addAttributeToFilter('product_location', array('like' => '%'.$location.'%'));
$_product = $obj->load($product_id); // Enter your Product Id in $product_id
$prdId1s[]=$_product;
}
```

Comment: everything is wrong with your code please let me know what you want to creat I will help you . Is product location is select , multiselect or text attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at below code this is the right way to fetching product from category and put filter onto that

```
foreach($type1 as $categoryid){
 productcollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryid)
             ->getProductCollection()
             ->addAttributeToFilter('product_location', array('like' => '%'.$location.'%'));

$_product = $obj->load($product_id); // I dont unserstand  why you have written this code
$prdId1s[]=$_product;
}
```

Comment: When i tried this it printing query not result

Comment: http://prnt.sc/ce1co1

Comment: check this its printing result not query

Comment: what you have tried please update your whole code again

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to get product collection of a category.

```
$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
foreach($type1 as $categoryid){   
    $category->load($categoryid); // this is category id
    $collection = $category->getProductCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('product_location', array('like' => '%'.$location.'%'))
            ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)) // this filter added to get only enabled product in collection
    ;
}
```